# Add North arrow and scalebar using ggsn

Tags: r, maps, ggmap

I'm looking for a method to produce maps including north arrow and scalebar using the `ggsn` package.

I have succeeded in adding the north arrow but need to add the scalar as well.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
mg  <- get_map(bbox(extent(geit_mb[[1]])*2), source="google", zoom=13)
bbox(extent(geit_mb[[1]])*2)
        min      max
s1 21.17131 21.25476
s2 69.85586 69.90750

maps <- ggmap(mg) + 
        geom_path(data = geit_4237, aes(x=location.long, y=location.lat)) +      
        scalebar(geit_4237, dist = 5, dd2km = TRUE, model = 'WGS84')

north2(maps, .75,.90)
```

I get the following error:

> Warning message: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_text).

What have I missed?

But running the scalebar bit alone I get these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In max(data$long) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(data$lat) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(data$lat) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In min(data$lat) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In max(data$lat) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
6: In min(data$lat) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
7: In sin(lat) : NaNs produced
8: In cos(phi) : NaNs produced
9: In sin(phi) : NaNs produced
10: In sin(phi) : NaNs produced
11: In sin(lat) : NaNs produced
12: In cos(phi) : NaNs produced
13: In sin(phi) : NaNs produced
14: In sin(phi) : NaNs produced
```

Output of:

```
 dput(bbox(extent(geit_mb[[1]])*2))


structure(c(21.17130645, 69.8558596, 21.25475825, 69.9075024), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("s1", "s2"), c("min", "max")))
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. What is the content of `geit_mb[[1]]`?

Comment: The content of the geit_mb[[1]] is a move bank object on which i calculate the bbox extent for the ggmap

Comment: I reshape my question. What is the output of `bbox(extent(geit_mb[[1]])*2)`?

Comment: min      max
s1 21.17131 21.25476
s2 69.85586 69.90750

Comment: Could you add the output of `dput(bbox(extent(geit_mb[[1]])*2))` to your question? Will make things easier.

Comment: done saving the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not so obvious how to add a scalebar to a ggmap. Here's what I managed, with a lot of help from reading the code.

Get a map and load the libraries

```
library("ggmap")
library("ggsn")
map <- get_googlemap(center =c(23.89, 52.74), zoom = 12, maptype = "hybrid")
```

Get the bounding box for the map and reformat it into a `data.frame` for `scalebar`

```
bb <- attr(map, "bb")
bb2 <- data.frame(long = unlist(bb[c(2, 4)]), lat = unlist(bb[c(1,3)]))
```

Add the scalebar to a ggmap

```
ggmap(map) + 
  scalebar(data = bb2, dist = 1, dd2km = TRUE, model  = "WGS84", 
    location = "topleft", 
    anchor = c(
      x = bb$ll.lon + 0.1 * (bb$ur.lon - bb$ll.lon), 
      y = bb$ll.lat + 0.9 * (bb$ur.lat - bb$ll.lat)
    )
  )
```

The `data` are the bounding box of the map.

`dist` gives the length of each section of the scalebar

`dd2km` should be TRUE as the map data are in decimal degrees (but the code just checks that this value is not null)

`model` gives the datum - WGS84 for google maps.

I found that setting `location` alone left the scale so close to the edge that the legend or bar was lost. Hence I use `anchor` to position the scale bar 10 % from the left, 90 % up. I still need to set `location` as this is linked to the direction that the scalebar is positioned relative to the anchor point.

Comment: excellent :) But, it shouldnt have been this cumbersome to do.